# Command to switch tab in gnome-terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal

Is there a way to switch tab of gnome-terminal from a script?
I know about xdotool, but I need to switch to the tab by name. May be there is the way to know list of tab names or curent tab name from console at least?

Comment: If switching between tabs isn't doable, switching between windows should be.

Answer (score 1):

No, gnome-terminal doesn't have such options.